# How can I increase index i in range python in if-clause?

Tags: python

```
a = "a4b4t8a3a3w2q5a8o9i8"
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  if a[i].isdigit() is False:
    print("detected letter")
    i +=5 #this does not increase the i by 5 each tiem I find a letter
```

This does not help the index 'i' jump forward by 5. Why?

Comment: I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785495/how-to-change-index-of-for-loop-in-python
Think this is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a[i + 5]
```

instead of

```
i + 5
```