# Python why loop behaviour doesn't change if I change the value inside loop

Tags: python

Let's say I wrote a piece of code :

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    i=11
```

Why doesn't the loop terminate now ?

Even when I do this :

```
n=10
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
    n=0
```

It doesn't effect the loop ?

I'm just wondering how python is managing loop variables ?

Comment: use while loop in case like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change index of for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785495/how-to-change-index-of-for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `range()` function returns a list that you're iterating over
Example `for i in range(5)` is equivalent to `for i in [1,2,3,4,5]`
The `for` loop stops when it receives a `StopIteration`

Now, in your first block,

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    i=11
```

i is assigned to 11 after printing, but after the assignment, the iteration finishes and i is reassigned to the next list element.

Moving the assignment before works as you'd expect

```
for i in range(10):
    i=11
    print i
```

Output:

```
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
```

In your second block:

```
n=10
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
    n=0
```

n is updated after `range()` has already generated it's list `[1...10]` so updating n has no effect

Answer (score 6):

Python `for` loops are based on iteration, not a condition. They are stopped when `StopIteration` is reached, not when a certain Boolean condition evaluates to `False`.

`range` creates a temporary range object that cannot be changed during iteration. After `range(10)` or `range(n)` or whatever is called, this object is completely independent of what was used to create it.

You were probably expecting something like this to happen (C code):

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", i);
    i = 11;
}
```

This is not how a for loop works in Python. It is more similar to this:

```c
int range[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
for (int count = 0; count < 10; ++count) {
    int i = range[count];
    printf("%d ", i);
    i = 11;
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice way of explaining what is different when using range! +1

Answer (score 2):

The `range()` function generates the integer numbers between the given start integer to the stop integer, which is generally used to iterate over with for Loop.

`i` is returned output not the assignment.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Answer (score 0):

The whatever code we give inside the for loop is taken as a single block and will execute 10 times from i=0 to 9.

Even if you assign i=11 or any other variable x=1 inside the for loop , it will print the value that we assigned 10 times.

Please find the attachments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are answering how to do `for loop`, OP is asking about the reason behind for it.