# Different ways of accessing list elements

Tags: python

This is surely a very numb question...
Let numbers=[0,1,2,3,4]. What's the difference between these two pieces of code? I would expect them to work the same way but the first one does not modify the list while the second does.

```
for item in numbers:
    item +=1

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] +=1
```

Comment: Do you know what `+=` is shorthand for?

Comment: The first one doesn't change the list elements, it just updates the variable `item`.

Comment: The first one is a kind of sugar for: ```for i in range(len(numbers)): item = numbers[i]; item += 1``` Then, it wont' update ```numbers``` at all. The second uses ```numbers``` directly => It's updated

Comment: Try doing `print(numbers)` after each piece of code.

Comment: `item` is a **reference** to an item in the numbers list, not an actual item in the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python why loop behaviour doesn't change if I change the value inside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799322/python-why-loop-behaviour-doesnt-change-if-i-change-the-value-inside-loop)

Answer (score 2):

The `item` variable in the for-loop is independent from the list so modifying it has no effect on the list (it only modifies the item variable).  But when you get the index (`i`) and use it to increase the i*th* item, then you are affecting with the original list's content.

Comment: Worth noting that this is true only for the immutable objects (like `int` in this case (probably)). Mutable objects could be changed with `item += 1`. It doesn't "modify" the `item` variable it rewrites the `item` reference with another integer reference.