# Is this possible Else condition to work after break & trying to change for loop value?

Tags: python, for-loop, break

## Create random numbers of 150 and take a uniform sample of 78

```
import numpy as np

population_data=np.random.randint(1,600,150) # 150 random numbers(integers) genereated 

sample_data=[]
sample_lenth=78

p=30/len(population_data)


for i in range(1,len(population_data)):

    if np.random.random() <=p:
        sample_data.append(population_data[i])
        print(i,len(sample_data))
        if sample_lenth==len(sample_data):
            break;
else: 
    i=10 # (basically wants to change the i value lower that for loop keep running )
    print(i)
        
           
    
print(len(sample_data))
print(sample_data)
```

for loop is running still 150 which is valid and I cant add more range in for loop as if i>150 then sample_data.append(population_data[i] ) will be out of range.

What I want to achieve is:
if sample_lenth==len(sample_data): then break else change the i value to any in between 1-150 that loop continues

Any help !!

Comment: You can use ՛random.sample()՛ to extract a sample from your dataset.

Comment: Thanks, @luca.vercelli yes, That can be done, but  I am more into break and else operation:


    else: 
        i=10 # (basically wants to change the value of i, lower than the exact value)
        print(i)

What wrong I am doing here,

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the `for...else` construct has nothing to do with what you are looking for.

**The `else` clause is executed at most once, after the for loop has finished.**

See e.g. https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

You cannot change the `i` variable inside a `for` loop. Probably you want to use a `while` loop. See e.g. [How to change index of a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785495)