# Yield in for ... in

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer

I came across some code like this:

```
def func(tree):
 nodes = tree
 for node in nodes:
  yield node
  nodes += [42]

gen = func([-42, 3, 1, 4, 159])

for i in range(10):
 print(next(gen))
```

Does this code have undefined behaviour?

Specifically, does:

```
for node in nodes:
 yield node
 nodes += [42]
```

show undefined behviour?

I know that:

```
for node in nodes:
 # yield node
 nodes += [42]
```

may cause unexpected behaviour because the variable we are iterating through (`nodes`) is being updated in the for loop.

Comment: Yes it will not work. Actually it will just cause an infinite loop and probably run into an error sooner or later.

Comment: No, it's not undefined

Comment: @SkryptX it *does* work. Why do you say it doesn't work? It is memory inefficient, but it works.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you consider code with a trivial and totally avoidable memory leak "working"? I would strongly argue against that. "Memory inefficient" is not the same as "Eating memory until it fails"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, why would the behavior be undefined?

The generator yields all original elements from the tree argument and then `42` to infinity.

```
>>> gen = func([1, 2, 3])
>>> next(gen)
1
>>> next(gen)
2
>>> next(gen)
3
>>> next(gen)
42
>>> next(gen)
42
>>> next(gen)
42
```

Extending `nodes` with `[42]` for each yield makes sure that the generator will never run out of numbers to yield.

The only problem is that if you call `next` enough times you will encounter a `MemoryError` because `nodes` grew too large.

Comment: This will run out of memory eventually? You're not returning 42 everytime... You're extending the list by 42 everytime and then returning it.

Comment: just as an aside, you can use `itertools.chain(iterable, itertools.repeat(42))` to get a memory efficient version of this.

Comment: @timgeb I think the `for node in nodes: nodes += [42]` is undefined behaviour because I read somewhere that changing the `y` in `for x in y` inside the loop causes the object to be reallocated or something making the variable we are iterating through invalid (something to do with how memory or pointers work).

Comment: @ubndpdhsc Nothing of what you read is true. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/3620003) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532461/3620003) answer for more details. Mutating or reassigning the loop variable might give you another result than what you wanted, but the behavior is well defined.